# Can't delete “.sass-cache” because its pathname is too long

Tags: terminal, file, macos, trash

I get the error `Can't delete “.sass-cache” because its pathname is too long.` when I try to empty my bin.

[image: Can't delete “.sass-cache” because its pathname is too long.]

sudo `rm -rvf ~/.Trash/*` doesn't work, it returns `zsh: no matches found: /Users/cmiksche/.Trash/*`

I am running macOS Monterey beta 12.1

Comment: The rm fails as it does not see all files try `rm -rvf ~/.Trash/.*` The file glob does not see hidden files. However your error and this seem unconnected what is the full path to .saas-cache ?

Comment: `rm -rvf ~/.Trash/.*` also fails with the same error. The full path is a very long and cascaded - I don't know how to output it because I can't navigate to the file using `cd` and the Finder also stops displaying me the last folders...

Comment: A way is get the longest directory you can and the mv that to a shorter path e.g. ~/.Trash/a

Comment: What happens if you do `cd ~/.Trash; ls -a; ls -al`?

Comment: @nohillside I get `ls: .: Operation not permitted` even though I use `sudo`...